# Reloading data in two viewmodels via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have an application with two viewmodels: one renders a form and the other renders a table containing form data.

When the form is successfully saved via an Ajax call, the table is reloaded. The form is also supposed to reload but I can't seem to make it happen. Based on the below, am I approaching the problem correctly?

```
function FormViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.loadForm = function () {
    ...
    }

    self.save = function () {
    success: self.loadForm();
             tvm.loadTable();
    }
}

function TableViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.loadTable = function () {
    ...
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(fvm = new FormViewModel(), document.getElementById("Form"));
fvm.loadForm();

ko.applyBindings(tvm = new TableViewModel(), document.getElementById("Table"));
tvm.loadTable();
```

Comment: Dumb question but do you put `self = this`? somewhere?  What does `.loadForm` do?

Comment: Yep - I've added where self = this in the question. .loadForm just contains my form element observables.

Comment: Just because it contains the observables doesn't mean that it will *reload* in any way though; maybe you can set up an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I see what you mean. The observables don't actually reload, the idea is that are just rebound to their default values. I'll set up a fiddle shortly

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/7/ I haven't yet added the save function or button. In my application, when I save, loadForm() doesn't rebind the form with it's original values as expected.

Comment: Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/11/ What's supposed to happen is that the form is rebound with it's original values when the Ajax call is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with the `7` version you posted originally.  This is not fully functional, but I think that I have probably identified your problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/FZ6K6/12/

There are two big problems that I see:

```
self = this;
```

You are doing this in two places.  This creates a global variable `self`, so inside of FormViewModel methods, `self` is actually TableViewModel.  Ack!  Simple to fix with:

```
var self = this;
```

Additionally, when you create a new observable via `ko.observableArray`, you need to rebind.  However, rebinding is bad.  Instead, you should only create the observable initially and then update its value as needed.  That is, do B., not A.

```
//A
self.load = function () { self.a = ko.observable(); };

//B
self.a = ko.observable();
self.load = function () { self.a(null); };
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I've accepted this as an answer because it got me on the right track. :)